# Why allowDeviceNameModification is not working in iOS 12 but working in iOS 13

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm

I have two Supervised device iOS 12 and iOS 13. 
I am Appling restriction profile in both device from MDM

```
 allowDeviceNameModification = false
```

both Devices not allowing me to change the name from the device side, 
which is justified from Apple doc it's working fine from the device side.

**but I am also facing very weird behavior in iOS 12 devices.
when I am trying to change the name from the MDM side it's not working, while it's working in iOS 13 device.**

Comment: Are your iOS 12 devices under supervised devices?

Comment: @Udhy yes both devices are supervised.